# Opening PDFs in SharePoint 2010 - different behaviour in different sites experienced

Tags: 2010, pdf, save

I have read the posts regarding opening PDFs in SharePoint without the need to save it first and the 2 options available: 1) Powershell script 2) Change browser file handling.

However, the issue I have is that on my site collection I have subsites that open PDFs directly in the browser, and other subsites that force me to save the PDF locally first. I have no idea why there is a difference in behaviour between sites. I have not made any amendments on the site collection which are anything to do with the 2 options mentioned above.

Does anyone have any ideas why there would be a difference of PDF-opening behaviour between different subsites?

Comment: Quick thoughts: Do both sites have the same "trust level" setting in your browser? http https?

Comment: Both sites are https.